# ASCII-art videogame edition

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

I thought it might be fun to throw this on here.
Generate an ASCII-art for one of your favorite videogames.

What you want to generate is up to you but it should meet 2 requirements.

1. It should be able to identify the game. So either a logo or
   something familiar like the triforce in Zelda. a pokeball for
   pokémon or an actual pokémon.
2. Make it solid.

I'm guessing the second requirement is a bit vague, I just dont know how to explain it so let me show you with the triforce.

```
Wrong  
       /\   
      /__\  
     /\  /\  
    /__\/__\

Right  
           #  
          ###  
         #####  
        #######  
       #       #  
      ###     ###  
     #####   #####  
    ####### #######
```

This is a popularity-contest, so be creative and dont worry about the length of your code.

#### Rules

- No external resources
- You can use any language you like

**Edit**
You are meant to write some kind of algorithm that will create your ascii art rather than simply arranging the characters.
*Sorry for changing the question*

Happy Coding!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an art contest, not a programming contest.

Comment: I will make this more clear in the question, ofcourse youre supposed to program it instead of simply arranging the characters manually.

Comment: Why was this closed? The edit was not enough? After the question was edited, it is looking like a programming contest for me, not simply an art contest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Bash

An actual pokémon? Ok. I present the Voltorb, seen from behind.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '\e[31m'    # escape character for red font
s=6
for i in `seq 8 2 16`; do
    if [ $i -ne 10 ]; then
        for j in `seq $s`; do
            echo -n ' '
        done
        for j in `seq $i`; do
            echo -n '#'
        done
        echo
    fi
    s=`expr $s - 1`
done
echo -e -n '\e[97m'    # escape character for white font
s=2
for i in `seq 16 -2 8`; do
    if [ $i -ne 10 ]; then
        for j in `seq $s`; do
            echo -n ' '
        done
        for j in `seq $i`; do
            echo -n '#'
        done
        echo
    fi
    s=`expr $s + 1`
done
echo -e '\e[0m'    # escape character for default font color
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Javascript

**Invaders !**

```
for(j=8,o='';j--;o+='\n')for(i=11;i--;)o+=1&"ĎĘƾŭĽļĽŭƾĘĎ".charCodeAt(i)>>j?'##':'  '
```

Output :

```
    ##          ##          
      ##      ##            
    ##############          
  ####  ######  ####        
######################      
##  ##############  ##      
##  ##          ##  ##      
      ####  ####
```

**Triforce**

```
for(j=8,o='';j--;o+='\n')for(i=15;i--;)o+=1&"āăćďėĳűǰűĳėďćăā".charCodeAt(i)>>j?'##':'  '
```

Output :

```
              ##              
            ######            
          ##########          
        ##############        
      ##              ##      
    ######          ######    
  ##########      ##########  
##############  ##############
```

Any 8-lines (can be extended to 16 easily) logo can be displayed with that code, you have to change only the encoding string.
Each character of the string corresponds to a column.
You can also declare a generic function :

```
function f(s){for(j=8,o='';j--;o+='\n')for(i=s.length;i--;)o+=1&s.charCodeAt(i)>>j?'##':'  ';return o}
f('ĎĘƾŭĽļĽŭƾĘĎ'); //invaders
f('āăćďėĳűǰűĳėďćăā'); //triforce
```

To encode the column (8bits), use `parseInt`, specify the bits with a `1` at the start to enforce unicode.

Example for the first part of the triforce :

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt('100000001',2),parseInt('100000011',2),parseInt('100000111',2),parseInt('100001111',2),parseInt('100010111',2),parseInt('100110011',2),parseInt('101110001',2),parseInt('111110000',2))
```

Output: `"āăćďėĳűǰ"`

Comment: That's brilliant! Even though you're using Unicode, I'll +1 for the clever use of bitwise and char operations.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2.7

```
#!/bin/python2

a,b=[[78,20],[2,20,47,28],[5,20,40,27],[0,23,37,23],[2,21,14,28],[0,24,29,32],[2,22,21,40],[4,19,20,42],[8,14,13,49],[7,75],[6,66],[5,65],[3,58],[2,48],[2,33],[2,30],[2,28],[1,28],[1,28],[1,28],[1,28],[1,27],[1,27]],[]
for l in a:
    c=' '
    b.append([])
    for i in l:
    b[-1].append(c*i)
        c=[' ','#'][c==' ']
b[4]=b[4][:2]+['        OBJECTION!!']+b[4][2:]
for l in b: print ''.join(l)
```

**Output**

```
                                                                              ####################
  ####################                                               ############################
     ####################                                        ###########################
#######################                                     #######################
  #####################        OBJECTION!!              ############################
########################                             ################################
  ######################                     ########################################
    ###################                    ##########################################
        ##############             #################################################
       ###########################################################################
      ##################################################################
     #################################################################
   ##########################################################
  ################################################
  #################################
  ##############################
  ############################
 ############################
 ############################
 ############################
 ############################
 ###########################
 ###########################
```

Of course, based on:

[image: Phoenix Wright]

It's not a particularly novel method of generating the output, nor is it fantastic ASCII art (it looks more like a gun than a pointer finger, and the spiky hair doesn't come across great), but there isn't enough Ace Attorney in here! :)

Answer (score 6):

### Game Maker Language

```
a="    "
b=a+a+a
c=b+b
d="------"
show_message(a+"  _=====_"+c+a+"   _=====_# "+a+"/ _____ \"+c+a+" / _____ \#   +.-'_____'-."+d+d+d+d+"---.-'_____'-.+#  /   |     |  '."+a+a+"S O N Y+a+a+"'  |  _  |   \# / ___| /|\ |___ \"+b+a+a+" / ___| /_\ |___ \#/ |      |      | ;  __"+a+a+"   _   ; | _         _ | ;#| | <---   ---> | | |__|"+a+a+" |_:> | ||_|   "+a+"(_)| |#| |___   |   ___| ;SELECT"+a+"   START ; |___   "+a+"___| ;#|\    | \|/ |    /  _"+a+" ___  "+a+"_   \    | (X) |    /|#| \   |_____|  .','' '', |___|  ,'' '', '.  |_____|  .' |#|  '-.______.-' /       \ANALOG/   "+a+"\  '-._____.-'   |#|"+b+"   |   "+a+"|"+d+"|"+a+"   |"+b+a+"#|"+b+"  /\   "+a+"/ "+a" \   "+a+"/\   "+b+"|#|"+b+" /  '.___.'"+a+a+"'.___.'  \"+b+"  |#|"+b+"/"+c+a+"\"+b+" |# \  "+a+a+"/  "+c+a+"\"+a+a+"   /#  \________/"+c+a+a+"\_________/")
```

**Result** (SE has too much whitespace, try copying to Notepad)

```
      _=====_                               _=====_
     / _____ \                             / _____ \
   +.-'_____'-.---------------------------.-'_____'-.+
  /   |     |  '.        S O N Y        .'  |  _  |   \
 / ___| /|\ |___ \                     / ___| /_\ |___ \
/ |      |      | ;  __           _   ; | _         _ | ;
| | <---   ---> | | |__|         |_:> | ||_|       (_)| |
| |___   |   ___| ;SELECT       START ; |___       ___| ;
|\    | \|/ |    /  _     ___      _   \    | (X) |    /|
| \   |_____|  .','' '', |___|  ,'' '', '.  |_____|  .' |
|  '-.______.-' /       \ANALOG/       \  '-._____.-'   |
|               |       |------|       |                |
|              /\       /      \       /\               |
|             /  '.___.'        '.___.'  \              |
|            /                            \             |
 \          /                              \           /
  \________/                                \_________/
```